# What are the advantages and disadvantages of having a hosted firewall?

Tags: firewall, isp

Would you rather have your firewall hosted or in house if you've got the skills to manage it?

What are to pros and cons of having a firewall hosted by your ISP in general?

Answer (score 1):

Big advantage is bandwidth saving.  If there is a firewall on the other end, and you get attacked in some high-bandwidth capacity, the traffic won't fill your line with the trash.  However, this means that the ISPs firewall config that they allow you to do (or will do with a phone call) is sufficient to block that sort of thing quickly.

I would make certain there is a simple textual representation of what they are doing on your behalf, so you can then move to another company without as much effort.  It's also handy for debugging.